First paragraph of first column runs the same width as single column first page
I'm using the overleaf template provided by a journal that I am submitting to that is found here. When I add my own text, the first page looks fine but the first paragraph of the second page (which is multiple columns) ends up being the same width as the first page width and running into the adjoining column. I also get an underfull box warning at the end of that paragraph. Using \indent or \newpage does not solve this problem. It also is not an issue in the following paragraphs. Any tips would be appreciated. Image of my compiled output attached for reference. Thanks!


It is fine to offer information on the original format. The problem is that, in general, the templates work as defined. This problem is a specific example of a modified template not working. This problem is about the modified form and actually contains no information that could show how the modified template does not works or be able to repeat the issue.

As somebody mentioned in a comment on your previous question, to help you effectively we need code for a complete but minimal example we can compile to reproduce the problem. In the previous case, we had a code snippet which happened to be enough. In this case, we've only got a 'template' which, given its provenance, presumably doesn't produce this behaviour by default. So the problem is due to some code you've not shared.

my crystal ball suggests a mistake in your abstract markup but hard to tell as you have provided no information about your input.

It could be that all you need is a \pagebreak command between two paragraphs.  If the template uses flowfram, paragraphs which are fomratted in one frame will retain the same width in the next one.  And while the paragraph appears on the second page, it could have been formatted on the first.

It seems that the text flow somehow  to a narrower column but that the new \hsize cannot come into effect until the end of the paragraph (after "point of care)"  but also seems that you already start a paragraph in "There is a gap", so it is not clear at all why. You can see the same symptom here but for the diagnosis of the disease we need your document cleaned of erything does not prevent you from compiling and still see this problem. You can use the lipsum package to replace your long real text for dummy text.

Is that the PNAS research template? You would need to figure out a good value for \firstpage{...}. See the comments in the template .tex file that starts "Use \firstpage to indicate which paragraph and line will start the second page and subsequent formatting"
